# Afnetworking - post json -> 400 bad Request

Tags: ios, objective-c, salesforce, afnetworking-3

Im using salesforce live agent rest api in ios app, trying to request chat but always fail with 400 request is not a valid ChasitorInit

```
NSDictionary *parameters =@{     @"SessionId"          :self.sessionId,
                                 @"OrganizationId"     :ORG_ID,
                                 @"deploymentId"       :DEPLOYEMENT_ID,
                                 @"buttonId"           :BUTTON_ID,
                                 @"userAgent"          :USER_AGENT,
                                 @"language"           :LANG,
                                 @"screenResolution"   :SCREEN_RES,
                                 @"visitorName"        :@"Test Visitor",
                                 @"prechatDetails"     :@[],
                                 @"prechatEntities"    :@[],
                                 @"receiveQueueUpdates":@"true",
                                 @"isPost"             :@"true"
                             };

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
manager.requestSerializer = serializer;

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:self.sessionKey forHTTPHeaderField:X_LIVEAGENT_SESSION_KEY];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"null" forHTTPHeaderField:X_LIVEAGENT_AFFINITY];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"1" forHTTPHeaderField:X_LIVEAGENT_SEQUENCE];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:API_V forHTTPHeaderField:X_LIVEAGENT_API_VERSION];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:ChasitorInit_path parameters:parameters progress:nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
          NSError* error;
          NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                                                               options:kNilOptions
                                                                 error:&error];
      } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      }];
```

Im using Afnetworking v3 ios8
The request body should be

```
{
"sessionId": "8f1cfb18-fbd1-4487-90d-e98c0a84e165",
"organizationId": "00D58000000OwMB",
"deploymentId": "57258000000L1mj",
"buttonId": "57358000000L24F",

"userAgent": "",
"language": "en-US",
"screenResolution": "1900x1080",
"visitorName": "Test Visitor",
"prechatDetails": [],
"prechatEntities": [],
"receiveQueueUpdates": true,
"isPost": true
```

}

What im i doing wrong ? Plz correct me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

400 Bad request means, you didn't form the request the way server expects.

Check the server logs for whats the issue...

May be it needs data in another form..

and try to check that,you are not passing null value to server..

Try like that:

```
 NSString *Loginurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://Enter your URL Here"];

    NSDictionary *params = @{     @"SessionId"          :self.sessionId,
                                 @"OrganizationId"     :ORG_ID,
                                 @"deploymentId"       :DEPLOYEMENT_ID,
                                 @"buttonId"           :BUTTON_ID,
                                 @"userAgent"          :USER_AGENT,
                                 @"language"           :LANG,
                                 @"screenResolution"   :SCREEN_RES,
                                 @"visitorName"        :@"Test Visitor",
                                 @"prechatDetails"     :@{},
                                 @"prechatEntities"    :@{},
                                 @"receiveQueueUpdates":@"true",
                                 @"isPost"             :@"true"
                             };

    NSLog(@"Sent parameter to server : %@",params);

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];



    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];


    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];


    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/html",nil];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/plain",nil];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:self.sessionKey forHTTPHeaderField:X_LIVEAGENT_SESSION_KEY];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"null" forHTTPHeaderField:X_LIVEAGENT_AFFINITY];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"1" forHTTPHeaderField:X_LIVEAGENT_SEQUENCE];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:API_V forHTTPHeaderField:X_LIVEAGENT_API_VERSION];

            AFSecurityPolicy* policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];

    [policy setValidatesDomainName:NO];

    [policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];



    [manager POST:Loginurl parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"Response from server :  %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);



        _str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        NSLog(@"%@",_str);


        [self getdata:responseObject];



    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error)

     {

         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];    
 }

#pragma mark-DataFromServer

-(void)getdata:(NSDictionary*)RegisterData

{


}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i updated the question please see the generated json

Comment: in params what's the error after replacing                                  @"prechatDetails"     :@{},  by  @"prechatDetails"     :@[ ],

Comment: changed and now got error "Invalid value around character 0."

Comment: 1) Try passing the X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY value as null. This prevents the session expiry.

2) If you copied your JSON from the online documentation example, it's wrong. You may want to use JSON lint to double check if your JSON is valid or not (I suspect this is most likely the issue in your case)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in my app. I resolve it by removing request and response Serializer. Only instantiate manager and called post method with parameter.

```
reqManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[reqManager POST:URLString parameters:parameters progress:nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

      } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      }];
```